# How to solve an equation with too many equal signs?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to ask how to solve an equation with many equal signs.

I came across this question while solving this :-
$2y+1=3y+2=4y+3=5y+4=6y+5=7y$

Please help me out with this equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Choose two of the equations and solve it. If that solution satisfies all equations then you're good. Else there is no solution.

Comment: @player3236: you probably mean "choose *one* of the equations".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I probably meant "expressions"

Comment: @player3236: ah, ok. Choose two of the expressions and solve it.

Comment: @player3236 I tried this but I didn't work

Comment: What do you mean  precisely ?

Comment: $y=-1$ satisfies all equations but the last. Aren't you missing a $+6$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I meant can you solve for x if X=2y+1=X=3y +2..... as  I mentioned.

Comment: You didn't mention anything. Since $y=-1$ satisfy most equations but not all, there is no solution where all equations hold.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this

Comment: In my textbook it was written after solving this you will get 2y+1=119 but I don't know how they got this solution.

Comment: If it was $2y+1=3y+2=4y+3=5y+4=6y+5=7y+6$ the solution would be $y=-1$

Comment: @Raffaele but it is not 7y+6

Comment: The equation is impossible

Comment: @Raffaele But why is this impossible